# Non-interactive transactions with Web3 interface

Tags: web3js, metamask

would like to build a blockchain simulator with web3 interface.
I use ganache and solidity.
my simulator is a microgrid simulator (autonomous energy community) where a house is represented by an eth address (with ganache)
However, as soon as I make a transaction or interact with a contract, a metamask notification appears.
is it possible to remove this notification in order to run my simulator which will proceed to multiple transactions without the user having approved these transactions.

Thank’s for response

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to disable MetaMask's prompt. It is a security measure to prevent access to a wallet without the user intervention.

If you are using ganache you should connect directly without passing through Metamask.

Answer (score 0):

For the simulation purposes, you want to use a programmatical wallet and not MetaMask.

You can emulate wallet with with web3.js or web3.py code.

- Store raw private keys as hexadecimal format (the private key is just a random uint256)
- Import private keys to web3.js or similar
- Sign any transactions directly with these private keys

[truffle-hdprovider](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/tree/develop/packages/hdwallet-provider) package allows you to use hierarchically deterministic keys in your JavaScript / TypeScript code. Then you can just `send()` transactions without triggering any prompts.